# DB2/400 : Difference beetwen BLOB and CLOB

Tags: db2-400

What's the difference beetwen BLOB and CLOB  on DB2/400 ?

This data has the same Length ( 1 through 2 147 483 647 )

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

CLOB = Character Large Object
BLOB = Binary Large Object

Characters can be translated between CCSIDs, binary data will not be.

If you're dealing with character data, XML, JSON, plain text, use a CLOB.

If you're dealing with binary data, .ZIP .PDF, then use a BLOB.

Example, you store a CCSID 37 (EBCDIC US ENGLISH) CLOB and retrieve it via JDBC.  The data will be translated to unicode by the JDBC driver.  The hexadecimal representation of the data will be different.

Same data as a BLOB will be returned unchanged, hexadecimal representation will be unchanged on both sides.

Comment: Ok, Thank's for your help.